# how to change form on change button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two json files "a.json" and "b.json". I need to show a different form when the user clicks each of the different buttons. My issue is that when I click on the first button it show the first form, but when I click on the second button it doesn't show the second form. I need to show one form at a time, i.e. when I click the second button it removes the first form and shows the second form.

```
  $scope.getFromAFile= function () {
      // body...
      var inputs=[];
      $http.get('a.json').success (function(data){
        var a=changeData(data);
         $scope.formFields=[]

              console.log('pp');

      console.log(data.studentName);
      console.log($scope);
      $scope.formFields = a['input'];


    }).error(function(err){
            alert(err);
        });

    }

        $scope.getFromBFile= function () {

      // body...
      $http.get('b.json').success (function(data){
        var a=changeData(data);
              console.log('pp');
 $scope.formFields=[]
      console.log(data.studentName);
      console.log($scope);
      $scope.formFields = a['input'];
    }).error(function(err){
            alert(err);
        });

    }
```

here is plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/tuMl02QcvZkCCIJPTW0r?p=preview

Comment: Worth mentioning that you're using a directive called [angular-formly](https://github.com/nimbly/angular-) to render the form.

Comment: @user3703527 Take a look at my answer

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan please check the json file..the form mis one field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Dont mix JQuery with AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/1575570)**

you can use **[ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)** and [**ng-show**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) for achieving such Task

```
<button ng-click="hideFormOne()">Hide Form One</button><!-- Hides Form One & Shows Form Two -->
<button ng-click="hideFormTwo()">Hide Form Two</button><!-- Hides Form Two & Shows Form One-->

<form ng-show="showFormTwo">
:
:

<form ng-show="showFormOne">
:
:
```

**script**

```
$scope.hideFormOne = function()
{
 $scope.showFormOne = false; // Hides Form One
 $scope.showFormTwo = true;  // Shows Form Two
}

$scope.hideFormTwo = function()
{
 $scope.showFormTwo = false; // Hides Form Two
 $scope.showFormOne = true;  // Shows Form One
}
```

Comment: But there is a issue that when you check json file.there is four field ,But it display only three

Answer (score 1):

If i understand u can use hide() function:

on document load u need hide both forms:

```
$('#form1').hide();
$('#form2').hide();
```

And on button click:

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
 $('#form1').show();
 $('#form2').hide();

});
$('#button2').click(function(){
 $('#form1').hide();
 $('#form2').show();

});
```

Comment: If you're using AngularJS, I would recommend using the Angular directives ngHide and ngShow instead of the .hide() and .show() functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two forms, eg formA and formB.

And then if user click on formA, hide formB or click on formB then hide formA.

Example if clicked formA:

```
$('formA').hide();
$('formB').show();
```

And example if clicked formB:

```
$('formA').show();
$('formB').hide();
```

**Here is [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZgZJZyaAZGWJ2tebpVKf?p=preview)**